# Перевод числа в двоичную систему, используя побитовый сдвиг

Tags: python, python-3.x, битовые-операции

Тема побитового сдвига для меня абсолютно нова, пытаюсь разобраться.

Я делю на 2, используя побитовый сдвиг, но не могу понять, как проверить наличие остатка при делении. `&1` не даёт результата, вернее дает 0, потому что работает с уже округлённым вниз числом.

```py
def ten_to_bi(n):
    ans = '0b'
    ans_add = ''
    while n != 1:
        n = n >> 1
        ans_add += n & 1  # эта операция проверяет число на чётность, и ошибка тут
    return ans + ans_add[::-1]
```

А вот так бы я решал без побитового сдвига:

```py
def ten_to(n):
    ans = '0b'
    ans_add = ''
    while n != 1:
        ans_add += str(n % 2)
        n = int(n/2)
    ans_add += str(n % 2)
    return ans + ans_add[::-1]
```

Но у меня задание по курсу сделать это именно с помощью побитовых операций.

Comment: +1 за отлично оформленный вопрос с собственными попытками решения) Маленькое уточнение - вы наверное имеете ввиду __побитовый__ сдвиг?

Comment: Да, вы правы, внес изменения. Благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачу можно решать по аналогии:

```py
def ten_to_bi(n):
    ans = '0b'
    ans_add = ''
    while n > 1:
        ans_add += str(n & 1)
        n >>= 1
    ans_add += str(n & 1)
    return ans + ans_add[::-1]
```

***Ваша ошибки:***

1. Складывали число со строкой:

   ```py
   str(n & 1)
   ```
2. Делали сдвиг ещё до того, как брали остаток:

   ```py
   ans_add += str(n & 1)
   n >>= 1
   ```
3. Забыли добавить последний остаток:

   ```py
   ans_add += str(n & 1)
   ```
4. Не учли крайний случай в обоих решениях (0):

   ```py
   while n > 1:
   ```

Comment: Большое спасибо, ошибка с while совсем обидная. После вашего ответа не осталось вопросов. Благодарю

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно сначала получать младший бит числа, а только потом его откусывать от числа.

В варианте без побитовых операций вы так и делаете

```
ans_add += str(n % 2) 
n = int(n/2)
```

С побитовыми операциями вам нужно поступать аналогично.

```
ans_add += str(n & 1)  # Получаем младший бит числа
n >>= 1  # Сдвигаем число на 1 бит вправо. То же самое, что и деление на 2.
```

Вы делаете наоборот. Из-за этого теряете бит.

P.S. В Python 3 целочисленное деление выполняется операцией `//`

```
n //= 2
```

Чтобы не делать в конце реверс строки, можно сразу записывать цифры в правильном порядке

```
ans_add = str(n & 1) + ans_add
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо.